# cant compile ' hover ' in scss : display:block - no reaction

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

my hover cant compile in scss in ul, li with display:block;

my "color" is changed before :hover but not "display".

in css it isnt problem

```
            a{
                display: block;
                color:bisque;
            }
            li{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                justify-content: center;
                justify-items: center;
                flex-flow: column;
                z-index:1;
                ul{ 
                 display:block;
                 flex-flow: column;
                  a{ 
                    &:hover{
                    color:red;
                  }
               }
             }
                a{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
                }
```

this cant compile in scss:

```
ul{ 
                display:none;
                flex-flow: column;
                &:hover{
                    display:block;
                }
            }
            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
            }
```

Comment: How are you supposed to hover something that isn't displayed?

Comment: resolve is li :hover ul as post below.thx

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for good intention

```
li{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            justify-items: center;
            flex-flow: column;
            z-index:1;
            ul{ 
                display:none;
                flex-flow: column;
            }
            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
            }
            &:hover{
                ul{
                    display:block;
                }
            }
        }
```